# I need to method get user input

Tags: java, methods

I need to method get two user input using 2d array in java.1st input data is user ID(eg-S001) second data is user name(eg-Tailer)
output like this [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-eNLfachOJZU3D_RQWt7SCBBFKoMj1Ny/view)

Comment: Please post a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with decent code that truly shows your problem and enough information to know what the problem is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a do-my-homework site, so it's not likely you will find anyone here willing to write your method for you.  But if you've written some code of your own that you're having trouble with, please share it, along with a description of the difficulty and we'll be happy to try to help.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new member of this site.

Comment: String[][] myArray = new String[5][1];
   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 
    System.out.printf("Enter Student ID");
    myArray [i][0]=input.nextLine(); 
    for (int j = 0; j <myArray[i].length ; j++){
     System.out.printf("Enter Student Name");  
     myArray [i][j]=input.nextLine(); 
    }  
     
   } this is my code.but i print array i can not get full array data

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Scanner is able to read from the command line.

Comment: No i need full method

Comment: What do you mean about full method?